# Javascript matching objects of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have this array, I wish to pick out all the names which have a URL which contains '/blekinge'.

Any way to do this with map? And present in a list?
I've come this far:

```
const allaOrter = orter.map((allOrt) =>
<li>{allOrt.url}</li>
)
```

What I would like to do is to have sort of an ifstatement or a forEach loop that picks out all the URLs which contains /blekinge and present those. But I dont know how...
The real array I'm working with is much bigger and contains loads of urls.
Maybe even make new arrays which contains those elements that have a common url.
I hope my provided example is enough for someone of you guys to help me out. :)

```
orter.json
[{
        "id": "2",
        "namn": "Blekinge",
        "url": "/blekinge"
    },
    {
        "id": "23",
        "namn": "Karlshamn",
        "url": "/blekinge/karlshamn"
    },
    {
        "id": "24",
        "namn": "Karlskrona",
        "url": "/blekinge/karlskrona"
    },
    {
        "id": "25",
        "namn": "Olofström",
        "url": "/blekinge/olofstrom"
    },
    {
        "id": "26",
        "namn": "Ronneby",
        "url": "/blekinge/ronneby"
    }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Demo :**

```js
const data = [{
        "id": "2",
        "namn": "Blekinge",
        "url": "/blekinge"
    },
    {
        "id": "23",
        "namn": "Karlshamn",
        "url": "/alpha/beta"
    },
    {
        "id": "24",
        "namn": "Karlskrona",
        "url": "/blekinge/karlskrona"
    },
    {
        "id": "25",
        "namn": "Olofström",
        "url": "/abc/def"
    },
    {
        "id": "26",
        "namn": "Ronneby",
        "url": "/blekinge/ronneby"
    }];
    
const res = data.filter((obj) => obj.url.indexOf('/blekinge') !== -1);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use array.prototype.filter method then map the returned array

```
const arr = [{
        "id": "2",
        "namn": "Blekinge",
        "url": "/blekinge"
    },
    {
        "id": "23",
        "namn": "Karlshamn",
        "url": "/blekinge/karlshamn"
    },
    {
        "id": "24",
        "namn": "Karlskrona",
        "url": "/blekinge/karlskrona"
    },
    {
        "id": "25",
        "namn": "Olofström",
        "url": "/blekinge/olofstrom"
    },
    {
        "id": "26",
        "namn": "Ronneby",
        "url": "/blekinge/ronneby"
    }]
    
let filtered = (a) => a.url.includes("/blekinge")


console.log(arr.filter(filtered))

then map the result
```

Comment: Thanks gonna try that on monday, just finished for the day. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should first try to narrow down by matching the object which contains the url `/blekinge` using the `filter` method. Once you have filtered, the resulting array can be used to present a list.

To keep things simple, I implemented an unordered list to present the result, but the core of what you need is in the resulting filtered array.

```js
let listElement = document.getElementById('name-list');

let data = [
  {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Blekinge",
      "url": "/blekinge"
  },
  {
      "id": "23",
      "name": "Karlshamn",
      "url": "/blekinge/karlshamn"
  },
  {
      "id": "24",
      "name": "Karlskrona",
      "url": "/blekinge/karlskrona"
  },
  {
      "id": "25",
      "name": "Olofström",
      "url": "/blekinge/olofstrom"
  },
  {
      "id": "26",
      "name": "Ronneby",
      "url": "/test/ronneby"
  }
];

let updateList = (list, content) => {
  let li = document.createElement("li");

  li.innerHTML = content;

  list.appendChild(li);
};
  
let filteredData = data.filter(elem => elem.url.indexOf('/blekinge') !== -1);

filteredData.map(elem => updateList(listElement, elem.name));
```

```html
<label for="name-list">Matching names</label>
<ul id="name-list">
<ul>
```